# Preventing a thread from owning a mutex twice

Tags: c#, mutex

I have a class with two functions - `OpenFile` and `CloseFile`. Respectively, they obtain a `mutex` and release it appropriately. This way I synchronize file access between processes and different threads. There is a situation, however, that a thread will `OpenFile` second time before it has closed it. I want to stop one thread from opening the file more than once.

Comment: What should happen if a thread tries to open it twice? `InvalidOperationException`?

Comment: A mutex can be acquired by the thread that owns it, it is re-entrant.  You could use a semaphore instead.  Note the very high odds for deadlock, consider the possibility that you are really just trying to work around a bug.

Comment: I need to make file read/write synchronous across threads and processes. Named mutexes serve well as long as some times the same thread tries to OpenFile() before it has closed it and the mutex is re-entered. In my application it would be enough to catch such threads and stop them from going on.

Answer (score 0):

As you have no code example it is difficult to see exactly what you are doing.

It appears that your locking pattern is wrong. You need to control the flow of opening and closing the file.

One way to approach to achieve this is to modify your file access, to a singleton type of pattern. Within the singleton you acquire a lock when the file is opened. Perform your write, close the file and unlock. All access is done through this one place so should help coordinate your file access.

This is a basic skeleton for multithreaded singleton, combined with the ReadWriterLock, as suggested earlier.

```
using System;

public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static volatile Singleton instance;
    private static object syncRoot = new Object();
    private static ReaderWriterLockSlim cacheLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

    private Singleton() {}

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
      get 
      {
         if (instance == null) 
         {
            lock (syncRoot) 
            {
               if (instance == null) 
                  instance = new Singleton();
            }
         }

         return instance;
      }
    }

    public void WriteToFile(string value)
    {
        cacheLock.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
            // perform your file write here
        }
        finally
        {
            cacheLock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }

}
```

Have a look at the notes and examples here, that should help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx

Comment: I think ReaderWriterLock does not synchronize between processes. I have no trouble using mutexes. The only problem with them is that they are recursive which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Thread.SetData` and `Thread.GetData` to store the value of some flag which determines whether a file is open or not by current thread.